# Android studio : leave my one-line methods as i've typed them when reformating code

Tags: java, android-studio, code-formatting

Is there an option in android studio to leave one-line method when reformatting code ? For example, for a simple getter, i prefer this style of coding:

```
public int getPosition() {return mPosition;}
```

But, when i reformat the code, this method is changed like this:

```
public int getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
 }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution.

1. Go to File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java
2. Click the **Wrapping and Braces** tab
3. Find the **Keep when reformatting** section
4. Turn on the **Simple methods in one line** checkbox

And it just go fine!

Comment: Kudos for giving the solution to your own problem. ("Nervermind I found a solution.")